# Application of Separation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show the following claim:

$U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and convex, and $f$ is a convex function from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}$. For fix $x_0 \in U$ there is a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following holds:

$f(x)\geq f(x_0)+\sum_{i=0}^{n}v_i (x-x_0)_i$.

I was thinking of an application of the following form of separation theorem on normed spaces $X$:

For $V$ (open) and $W$ disjoint convex sets there is a $x^* \in X^*$ such that $Re(x^*(v)) < Re(x^*(w))$ $\forall v\in V$ and $w\in W$;

to the set $V:=\{(t,x)$ so that $x\in U $ and $ t> f(x)\}$.

Do you have any suggestions how this works out?